# Ошибка групповой политики отказано в доступе. Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

Не заходит в gpedit.msc

> Локальная политика безопасности

в Windows 7
Захожу под администратором

[image: Вот так выглядит ошибка]

Comment: Win7 у вас какая?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional 64x-разрядная,  SP1 не стоит